# HTTP POST contents in Haskell

Tags: http, networking, haskell

I'm trying to post some data to a server in Haskell and the server side is coming up empty.

I'm using the Network.HTTP library for the request.

```
module Main (main) where

import Network.URI (URI (..), parseURI, uriScheme, uriPath, uriQuery, uriFragment)
import Network.HTTP
import Network.TCP as TCP

main = do
         conn <- TCP.openStream "localhost" 80
         rawResponse <- sendHTTP conn updateTest
         body <- getResponseBody rawResponse
         if body == rqBody updateTest
           then print "test passed"
           else print (body ++ " != " ++ (rqBody updateTest))

updateURI = case parseURI "http://localhost/test.php" of
                  Just u -> u

updateTest = Request { rqURI = updateURI :: URI
                     , rqMethod = POST :: RequestMethod
                     , rqHeaders = [ Header HdrContentType   "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
                                   ] :: [Header]
                     , rqBody = "Test string"
                     }
```

This test is returning the empty string as the response body from the server, when I think it should be echoing the "Test string" post.

I would ideally like to replicate the functionality of:

```
curl http://localhost/test.php -d 'Test string' -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

and am validating results with serverside test.php:

```
<?php
print (@file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Am I doing this wrong or should I just be trying another library?

Comment: I suggest to try and sniff the communication using "wireshark" or a similar program to see the actual content getting sent/received. this will pinpoint you to the problem much better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a `Content-Length` HTTP header, whose value must be the length of the raw posted data:

```
updateTest = Request { rqURI     = updateURI
                     , rqMethod  = POST
                     , rqHeaders = [ mkHeader HdrContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                                   , mkHeader HdrContentLength "8"
                                   ]
                     , rqBody    = "raw data"
                     }
```

Answer (score 3):

And with `http-conduit`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Network.HTTP.Conduit
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main = do
  initReq <- parseUrl "http://localhost/test.php"

  let req = (flip urlEncodedBody) initReq $
             [ ("", "Test string")
--             ,
             ]

  response <- withManager $ httpLbs req

  L.putStr $ responseBody response
```

The `"Test string"`, in the above example, is urlEncoded before being posted.

You can also set the method, content-type, and request body manually. The api is the same as in http-enumerator a good example is:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5614946